# Is there a way to send a file to a specific topic in a telegram group with telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I have a script that detect every time i make a clip with shadowplay. I want to make it send the video to my telegram group in the specific topic.

The closes i was able to get was sending to the "General" topic with this code

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
group_id = ''
topic_name = ''

with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.send_file(group_id, 'test.jpg')
```

But i want to make so it sends the file to a determined topic. In their changelog (v1.26) it seems that they should be accepting topics by now.